# Reading tabular data using python

Tags: python

I have a file containing numerical data in tabular format.It has total 6 column. I want to read and store values of 5 columns in 5 dimensional array and 6th column in to another array.
I tried to use `loadtxt()` of `numpy` but it load all columns in to one. Even I tried to use `loadtext()` with `unpack` parameter , but it store each column in to different variable.
I searched "stackoverflow" for same type of question but did not find anything.
Below is the example of my data

```
5000    0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  121.301
6300    0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  119.541
8000    0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  117.151
10000   0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  115.391
12500   0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  112.241
16000   0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  108.721
```

Comment: You could use `pandas` `read_table` function

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package with [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) methods:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data ="""
5000    0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  121.301
6300    0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  119.541
8000    0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  117.151
10000   0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  115.391
12500   0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  112.241
16000   0   0.3048  71.3    0.00266337  108.721
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', header=None)

a = df.iloc[:, :5].values
b = df.iloc[:, 5].values

In [192]: a
Out[192]: 
array([[  5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  6.30000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  8.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  1.00000000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  1.25000000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  1.60000000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03]])

In [193]: b
Out[193]: array([ 121.301,  119.541,  117.151,  115.391,  112.241,  108.721])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution using NumPy without pandas, consider reading in the whole data and then using [`np.hsplit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html#numpy.hsplit):

```
In [75]: data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')

In [76]: d, e = np.hsplit(data, (-1,))     # split at the final column

In [77]: d
Out[77]: 
array([[  5.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  6.30000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  8.00000000e+03,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  1.00000000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  1.25000000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03],
       [  1.60000000e+04,   0.00000000e+00,   3.04800000e-01,
          7.13000000e+01,   2.66337000e-03]])

In [78]: e
Out[78]: 
array([[ 121.301],
       [ 119.541],
       [ 117.151],
       [ 115.391],
       [ 112.241],
       [ 108.721]])
```